# Yaml Unmarshal won't parse YAML to struct

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to load a config file into a struct in Go. I'm getting no errors thrown, but my structure isn't modified at all. The way I'm doing it matches most examples I found online so I'm not really sure what's wrong.

```
type Config struct {
  hostOrigin string
}

const configName string = "config.yml"

func readConfig() (Config, error) {
  config := Config{}

  file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configName)
  if err != nil {
    return config, err
  }

  fmt.Println(string(file))

  err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &config)
  if err != nil {
    return config, err
  }

  spew.Dump(config)
  ...
}
```

My output is:

```
---
hostOrigin: testing

(main.Config) {
 hostOrigin: (string) ""
}
```

The file data is being output correctly, so it looks like the file is being read fine. But the structure isn't filled in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go Unmarshaling YAML into struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544146/go-unmarshaling-yaml-into-struct)

Comment: Tried that, `hostOrigin string `yaml:"host_origin"`` and changed my yaml to `host_origin: testing`, no difference though.

Comment: Simply changing `hostOrigin string` to `HostOrigin string` in the Go file and `host_origin` to `hostorigin` in the YAML file fixed it for me. I was also able to still use the original `hostOrigin` in the YAML by adding the `yaml:"hostOrigin"` struct tag to the newly renamed `HostOrigin` field in the Go file.

Comment: Strange, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Not strange. Same as with JSON, only *exported fields* (those starting with a capital letter) will be unmarshaled.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `hostOrigin` field is private. After renaming it to `HostOrigin` it should be working fine.